# How do I loop through child array and check if component exists React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

Currently I want to loop through all the child components and check if all the components exist with React Testing Library. The test below gave me the following error:

> TypeError: component.contains is not a function

Not sure what is wrong with this test, but it seems it cannot test based on the test ID.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { RandomMeals } from '../RandomMeals/RandomMeals';
import ListMeals from '../ListMeals/ListMeals';
import { SearchBar } from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import { TopBar } from '../TopBar/TopBar';
import SearchResult from '../SearchResult/SearchResult';

export const AppComponent = () => (
  <div className="app-container" data-testid="app-component-test">
      <TopBar/>
      <div className="column app-mobile app-desktop-left">
        <RandomMeals/>
        <SearchBar/>
        <SearchResult/>
      </div>
      <div className="column app-mobile app-desktop-right">
        <ListMeals/>
      </div>
  </div>
)

test("It should check if components exist", () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <AppComponent/>
        </Provider>
    );

    const component = screen.getAllByTestId("app-component-test");
    console.log(component);
    expect(component.contains(<RandomMeals/>)).toBe(true);
});
```

[image]

Comment: `getAllBy*` returns an array. `Array#contains` is not a function, hence the error you are getting.

Comment: Can you try `expect(component).contains(<RandomMeals/>);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that `<RandomMeals />` is being rendered, you should query based on that element:

```js
function RandomMeals(props) {
  return <div data-testid="random-meals-test">...</div>
}

test("It should check if components exist", () => {
  const screen = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppComponent/>
    </Provider>
  );

  expect(screen.getByTestId("random-meals-test")).not.toThrow()
  // alternatively
  expect(screen.queryByTestId("random-meals-test")).toBeTruthy()
});
```

To answer your question about what's wrong with the test, `getAllByTestId` returns an array of DOM nodes that match the query. And `Array#contains` is not a method in JavaScript. You could use `getByTestId` to return a single DOM node, which does have a contains method, but even in that case you cannot pass arbitrary JSX as an argument.